# Equal indexed inductive types implies equal indices

Tags: coq

Let's have an inductive type `foo` indexed by `x : X`.

```
Parameter X : Type.

Inductive foo : X -> Type :=
| constr : forall (x : X), foo x.
```

I'm curious, if `foo x = foo y` implies `x = y`. I'm out of ideas how to prove this.

```
Lemma type_equality_implies_index_equality : forall (x y : X), foo x = foo y -> x = y.
```

If this can't be proven, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It cannot be proved. Consider the following special case of the theorem, when we set `X := bool`:

```
foo true = foo false -> true = false
```

Given that `true` and `false` are different, if the theorem were provable, it should be possible to show that `foo true` and `foo false` are different. The problem is that these two types are *isomorphic*:

```
Inductive foo : bool -> Type :=
| constr : forall (x : bool), foo x.

(* An isomorphism between foo true and foo false *)
Definition foo_t_f (x : foo true) : foo false := constr false.
Definition foo_f_t (x : foo false) : foo true := constr true.

(* Proofs that the functions are inverses of each other *)
Lemma foo_t_fK x : foo_f_t (foo_t_f x) = x.
Proof. unfold foo_f_t, foo_t_f. now destruct x. Qed.

Lemma foo_f_tK x : foo_t_f (foo_f_t x) = x.
Proof. unfold foo_f_t, foo_t_f. now destruct x. Qed.
```

In Coq's theory, it is not possible to show that two isomorphic types are different without assuming extra axioms.  This is why an extension of Coq's theory such as [homotopy type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_type_theory) is sound. In HoTT, isomorphic types can be shown to be equal, and if it were possible to prove your theorem, HoTT would be inconsistent.

Comment: My head hurts, but I think I get it. Would you have a reference for the statement "In Coq's theory, it is not possible to show that two isomorphic types are different without assuming extra axioms." ?

Comment: And is it possible to show `(x <> y) -> (foo x <> foo y)`? I'm really confused in this world without principle of excluded middle.

Comment: The best reference I know (though maybe not the most accessible) is Hofmann and Streicher's paper "The Groupoid Interpretation of Type Theory". As Hofmann puts it (https://ncatlab.org/homotopytypetheory/files/HofmannDMV.pdf), we can have a sound extension of Martin-Löf type theory where isomorphic types are equal. This result also applies to Coq's theory.

Comment: And no, it is not possible to show the contrapositive. The counterexample I gave with true and false would also contradict that statement.